# Is there a way to have a program accept capitalized and uncapitalized inputs?

Tags: python, encryption, lowercase, capitalization

As the title says, I have my program functioning with capitalization but I would like it to have compatibility with uncapitalized and capitalized inputs. It should return as capitalized encryption.

```
decrypted = b"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.1234567890 "
encrypted = b"SE2RL.1W5A0Z8D7H4B9M6JX3FTNVQGPUOYCKI "

encrypt_table = bytes.maketrans(decrypted, encrypted)
decrypt_table = bytes.maketrans(encrypted, decrypted)

result = ''
choice = ''
message = ''

while choice != 'X':
    choice = input("\n Do you want to encrypt or decrypt the message?\n E to encrypt, D to decrypt or X to exit program. ")

    if choice == 'E':
        message = input('\nEnter message for encryption: ')
        result = message.translate(encrypt_table)
        print(result + '\n\n')

    elif choice == 'D':
        message = input('\nEnter message to decrypt: ')
        result = message.translate(decrypt_table)
        print(result + '\n\n')

    elif choice != 'X':
        print('You have entered an invalid input, please try again. \n\n')
```

Comment: You can use `.lower()` to transform all chars to lower case and `.upper()` to transform all chars to uppercase.

Comment: Not exactly, but I believe the .lower()/.upper() clause works. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You could either add all the lowercase letters to your `decrypted` string, or you could use `.upper()` on the user input.

Also, this is technically a substitution cipher. To make it an true "encryption" you need to have a key that "unlocks" the encrypted text. See the [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) for a very simple example (in fact it is a kind of substitution cipher itself :P), where the key is the number of shifts. Or see [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), which is arguably the best encryption algorithm out there so far.